# How smart cards are blocked?

Tags: cryptography, smartcard

I have a Yubikey NFC 5, when I enter a wrong PIN or PUK three times the smart card is blocked.

Can someone please explain to me how it is blocked ? Does the PIN/PUK functionality is disabled somehow ? Does it set a secret PIN (pretty stupid I believe) ?

How can I block or unblock a Yubikey (or any smartcard) programmatically ?

Comment: Read the support docs for [User PIN lockout](https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000010465-smart-card-pin-unlock-reset-operational-approaches#User_PIN_Lock_Outht8nr9). The smart card is disabled not blocked - as in the physical key stops working.